# Unable to align imported S3 bucket terraform configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have imported an existing S3 bucket to my `terraform` state.

I am now trying to reverse engineer its configuration and pass it to the `.tf` file.

Here is my file

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  provider = "aws.eu_west_1"
  bucket   = "my-bucket"

  grant {
      type        = "Group"
      permissions = ["READ_ACP", "WRITE"]
      uri         = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
    }

  grant {
      id          = "my-account-id"
      type        = "CanonicalUser"
      permissions = ["FULL_CONTROL"]
  }
```

Here is my `terraform plan` output

```
  ~ aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket
      acl:                                                     "" => "private"
```

No matter what value I use for the `acl` I **always** fail to align my `tf` with the existing `acl` configuration on the S3 bucket, e.g.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  provider = "aws.eu_west_1"
  bucket   = "my-bucket"
  acl.     = "private"
```

corresponding `plan` output:

```
Error: aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket: "acl": conflicts with grant
Error: aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket: "grant": conflicts with acl
```

and another:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  provider = "aws.eu_west_1"
  bucket   = "my-bucket"
  acl.     = ""
```

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  provider = "aws.eu_west_1"
  bucket   = "my-bucket"
  acl.     = ""
```

so if I use no value for acl, `terraform` shows the `acl` will change from non-set to `private`

If I use any value whatsoever, I get an error.

Why is that?

Comment: Which version of TF are you using?

Comment: version `0.11.4`

Answer (score 2):

This is an observation on 0.13 but still might help:

If I create a bucket using your original code (i.e. with no acl line), the resulting TF state file still includes a `"acl": "private",` attribute for the bucket. If I then add an acl="private" definition in the TF code, I also get `"acl": conflicts with grant` when trying to apply.

But what's really odd is that if I delete the `acl="private"` definition (i.e. revert to your original code), and also delete the `"acl": "private",` attribute line from the state file, then the plan (including a refresh) shows that the bucket will be updated in place with this: `+ acl = "private"`. Applying this seems to work fine, but then a second apply shows that the grants have been lost and need to be reapplied.

So it seems to me that there's a bug in the S3 state refresh that might also affect the import, and in addition clearly removing the acl attribute from state makes it then incorrectly apply as a default overriding any grants. I think it might be worth using your code to create a new bucket, and then compare the state definitions to bring over any bits the original import missed.